# Snowflake Join does not return null values condition matching records from 2 tables

Tags: join, null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matching

I have a header table and a transaction table.
The header table has Id value Null and description has something and Transaction table having Id as null for description something.

Now when I join on `Header.Id = Transaction.Id` I should have Id having matching values as well as null value as id matching with null value in transaction table.

Like the below query:

```
SELECT 
    SH.HEADER_COLID,
    SH.HEADER_COLDESCRIPTION,
    S.SALEORDER_MONTH,
    S.SALEORDER_YEAR,
    SUM(S.SALEORDER_AMT),
    SUM(S.SALEORDER_QTYCASES),
    SUM(S.SALEORDER_QTYWGHTPNDS)
FROM SDS_HEADERS SH,  SALEORDERS S  
WHERE SH.HEADER_COLID = S.DIVISION  
    AND SH.COLUMN_ID =1  
    AND S.OPEN_CLOSE='false' 
    AND S.SALEORDER_YEAR='2021'
GROUP BY SH.HEADER_COLID, SH.HEADER_COLDESCRIPTION, 
    S.SALEORDER_MONTH, S.SALEORDER_YEAR
ORDER BY SH.HEADER_COLID, SH.HEADER_COLDESCRIPTION, 
    S.SALEORDER_MONTH, S.SALEORDER_YEAR ASC
```

I get matching records for `SH.HEADER_COLID  = S.DIVISION` but Null value for HEADER_COLID should be matched against DIVISION null values but I am not getting these records. I need them please help on how to achieve this in snowflake.

Answer (score 3):

> Now when I join on Header.Id=Transaction.Id I should have Id having matching values as well as null value as id matching with null value in transaction table.

To treat `NULL=NULL` as true, [NULL safe operator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from.html) could be used:

```
ON Header.Id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM Transaction.Id
```

---

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT 1 AS id, 'a' AS c UNION
SELECT 2, 'b'            UNION
SELECT NULL, 'c';

CREATE TABLE t2 AS
SELECT 2 AS id UNION
SELECT 3       UNION 
SELECT NULL;
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
JOIN T2
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID;
-- id   c   id
-- 2    b   2

SELECT *
FROM T1
JOIN T2
  ON T1.ID IS NOT DISTINCT FROM T2.ID;
-- id   c   id
-- 2    b   2
-- NULL  c  NULL
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b85b3ba158db29c7714f56f5014114ef)**

EDIT:

Different approaches are possible:

1. ON col1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM col2
2. ON (col1 = col2 OR col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL)
3. ON EQUAL_NULL(col1, col2)

The usage of specific version depends on taste/convention. `IS DISTICT FROM` may seems esoteric at first but it is defined in SQL Standard. Related:[The IS DISTINCT FROM predicate by Lukas Eder](https://blog.jooq.org/the-is-distinct-from-predicate/).

Second approach is very explicit about the intent and compatible between multiple RDBMSes though is not conscice.
The third approach is using a function EQUAL_NULL that is product specific.

Comment: there's also `EQUAL_NULL(a, b)` in Snowflake https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/equal_null.html

Comment: @DavidGarrison Yes, EQUAL_NULL could also be used. The `IS DISTINCT FROM` predicate is defined in SQL Standard so it should be preferred.

Comment: I would disagree, the most concise SQL should be written, `EQUAL_NULL` has a documentation entry where `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is an abstract intent. And while I get the "transport SQL" idea, writing things in lowest comment denominator form leads to harder to read SQL that required.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim The usage depends on taste/convention. I disagree that [IS DISTINCT FROM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is-distinct-from.html) is an  abstract intent.  Having option to choose between SQL Standard predicate vs product specific function I would prefer standard(unless code convetion requires otherwise - consistency is a key).

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I agree though that it may look odd at the begining because `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM `  predicate seems to be doing non-equal comparison. Something like `col1 IS col2` would be much anticipated(like SQLite https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c1c9fff39566de0c041cbe89cc12da7f).